# Change Date format in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a variable "month" in SQL DB with 2 different formats: `yyyy-mm` and `yyyy-m` (e.g., 2015-11, 2016-1). When I try to sort the 'month" (ascending or descending), it is not showing properly due to this format difference. How to change the `yyyy-m` format to `yyyy-mm?`

Comment: SO we need use datatype **date**

Comment: What is the RDBMS you are using?

Comment: Use `date` data type, and you'll never have problems like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can be certain that it's never going to be anything other than those exact formats you can insert a zero at a known point in the string -

```
SELECT  MonthField,
        CASE WHEN LEN(MonthField)=6 THEN 
            LEFT(MonthField,5)+'0' + RIGHT(MonthField,1)
            ELSE MonthField
        END AS MonthField_Cleaned
FROM    SourceTable
```

But if at all possible you'd be better off cleaning whatever's creating the data, and ideally storing the data as actual dates rather than strings representing the months to ensure they can't get mixed up and you can use the DBMS' date manipulation functions.

Comment: That would be MSSQL code. It's a while since I've worked with MySQL but it'd be pretty similar from memory.